# Pycharm type checker - expected Series, got int

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting, typechecking

I have very simple Python function that subtracts scalar value from pandas Series:

```
def sub(x: pd.Series, a: int) -> pd.Series:
    return x - a
```

It works as expected. I'm using type hints to enable type checker directly in my PyCharm IDE. The issue here is I get this warning message:

> Expected type 'Series', got 'int' instead

As you can see in the image below:

[image: PyCharm type checker message]

I understand that Python is dynamically typed language so in some cases type checking with type hints has its own limitations. But this sounds as a clear case to me. Do you know how to deal with it? Or am I missing something in my simple code?

(I am using Python 3.8.2, PyCharm 2020.1 - Professional Edition)

Comment: Maybe, as an alternative, you could use `return x.sub(a)`?

Comment: Sure, that would work, but it raises another questions for me - why PyCharm does not list `sub` when I type `x.`? It shows many methods that are in the API of `pd.Series` but not this one. I would like to use type hints and other stuff to help me code faster and better, but this is a bit confusing. I will try to dive deeper.

Comment: Please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-18095 (thumbs up near the issue title)